# UISplitViewController incorrect display of colors if I using toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a little problem with my app D:
When I am using UIToolbar in DetailVC, I am getting wrong colors of UINavigationBar and UITabBar in MasterVC. The problem can be reproduced only with iPhones Plus, while switching from portrait mode to landscape (or reverse). After changing screen orientation, UINavigationBar and UITabBar are turning grey (grey is default background color of UISplitView). If I set value of BarTintColor not to nil in UIToolBar, the problem doesn`t exist.

Well, is there any way to use nil value of barTintColor in UIToolbar and have cool blur effect? Thanks

Screenshots:

[image]

Normal state: after starting application and opening this controller in landscape mode

[image]

Bug: after starting application and opening this controller in portrait mode and switching screen orientation to landscape mode

---

You can reproduce this problem by using the same Storyboard. I have not used constraints.

[image]

Comment: How to reproduce your result on other's machine? You didn't say that clear. And you want to get help?

Comment: @OwenZhao, pardon me. I attached storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In my test just set 'barTintColor' of UIToolbar to .clear is enough.

## Update

You need a UISplitViewControllerDelegate.

```
extension SplitViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func primaryViewController(forExpanding splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let mainViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first?.children.first

        if let bar = (mainViewController as? MainTableViewController)?.tabBar {
            if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                bar.barTintColor = .clear
            } else {
                bar.barTintColor = nil
            }
        }

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController!)

        return navController
    }
}
```

### Theory

Create another UINavigationController to avoid the default faulty one.

Comment: Yes, setting color to UIToolbar solves the UINavigationBar display problem, but in this case, the blur behind the UIToolbar looks different than with a value of nil. My goal is to keep the standard blur

Comment: I didn't find a resolution yet. However, whenever you click a cell on the left, the bar will turn to normal again. So this should be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, however, the issue is still not resolved. The method described above only masks the problem, but does not solve it. Adding additional UINavigationController leaves everything unchanged.

Comment: This is a bug. No one but Apple can fix it. My solution is a workaround. This is a common move for a bug.